# Microsoft Graph API call to create a CSV file using JSON data from another query

Tags: json, api, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a simple way to use Graph API to take a JSON result from another query and write it to a CSV file in a particular Document library in SharePoint? I thought this would be straightforward, but I have only found examples for uploading an existing file.